# select all distinct and get all rows of each distinct values from the same table

Tags: sql

i have the following table structure

```
------------------------------------------
banner_id   Date           banner_action 
------------------------------------------
1        | 01-01-2011  |       1
1        | 01-01-2011  |       2
1        | 01-01-2011  |       3
1        | 02-01-2011  |       1
1        | 02-01-2011  |       1
1        | 02-01-2011  |       1
2        | 02-01-2011  |       2
2        | 01-01-2011  |       1
3        | 01-01-2011  |       1
```

i want to select all distinct dates and then want to count the same banner_action for the banner_id=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(banner_action)
FROM table
WHERE banner_id = 1
GROUP BY Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this, I'm not totally certain what you want from the question.

I assume your table is called `bannerActions`

```
SELECT
             Date
            ,banner_action
            ,count(Date) actionCount
    FROM
            bannerActions
    GROUP BY
             Date
            ,banner_action
            ,banner_id
    HAVING
            banner_id = 1
```